# Proof about Existence of Stable Matching

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques

I've read the stable matching chapter in Kleinberg and Tardos's *Algorithm Design* and was wondering how one can show whether a stable matching under a given set of constraints exists. K&T introduce a modified algorithm that generalizes Gale-Shapely with forbidden pairs. They write

> We will show that there is always a stable matching, even in this more general model with forbidden pairs

but do not provide the tools to write rigorous proofs on the **existence** of a stable matching.

Here's an example: is there a stable matching in which everyone is matched with someone in the top-half of their rankings? You can set the forbidden set to be the the set of pairs $\{ (m, w) \in M \times W \mid {\text{rank}_m(w) > n} \lor {\text{rank}_w(m) > n} \}$ and see if the resulting stable matching is "top-half perfect", i.e., everyone does end up matched with the top-half of their rankings, and everyone in the cumulative top-half is accounted for. This is trivially done if the algorithm outputs `YES`. But how would you prove in the case that the algorithm outputs `NO`?

Perhaps this can be done by reasoning about instabilities, e.g., creating a supposed arbitary stable matching and finding an instability? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: By a 'general model' the book means the preference lists are arbritary (they can be anything), not the constraints on the matching. In other words, the preference lists can be anything but the constrainst on the matching are always that it must be perfect (everyone is matched) and there isn't any instability.

Comment: As for your second question I'm not sure if I understand it. Are you asking if there is a "top-half perfect" stable matching for every preference list? Or are you trying to find an algorithm for finding a top-half perfect stable matching? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but if my wording was unclear, maybe my answer will help.